# sort controls on two fields in crystal reports

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I would like to more than 1 interactive sort controls in my Crystal Report. Is this possible wihout grouping?

My report looks like this

```
person
   orderID  date amount
   ...      ...  ...
```

While the report is grouped on person (sorted alpabetically which is fine) i would like to give the end user the possibility to sort the data (within the person group) on on every field.

Excel can do it so i'am having my hopes up for crystal!

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can do that with the following steps:

1. Open the "Record Sort Expert". You should see your person group already in there.
2. Add every field you want to allow the user to sort on to the "Sort Fields". It doesn't matter whether it's ascending or descending as the user will be able to change this.
3. Go back to the designer and right-click the field heading (or any other field where it would make sense to put the sort control) and select "Bind Sort Control" and select the appropriate field. If you're right-clicking on the date column, select date, and so on.
4. Repeat step #3 for every column you want to be able to sort on.

Now you should have interactive up/down arrows on each field heading allowing you to sort on each column from within the results.